# If statement in javascript not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

This if statement is meant to change text to one of the colors with a button for each color. However, every button only changes the text to red as is. I'm not sure what i am doing incorrectly.

Javascript:

```
function colorFunction() {

if (document.getElementById("red")) {
document.getElementById('test').style.color = "red";

}else if(document.getElementById("blue")) {
document.getElementById('test').style.color = "blue";

}else if (document.getElementById("black")) {
document.getElementById('test').style.color = "black";

}

}
```

Html:

```
<button id="red" style="background-color:red" type="button" onclick="colorFunction()"><font color="white">Red Text</font></button>


<button id="blue" style="background-color:blue" type="button" onclick="colorFunction()"><font color="white">Blue Text</font></button>

<button id="black" style="background-color:black" type="button" onclick="colorFunction()"><font color="white">Black Text</font></button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("red")` returns a dom element which is a truthy value so always the first `if` will be executed if the `red` element is present rest of the `else...if` will be ignored

Comment: what are you really trying to do

Comment: where is the element with id test

Comment: I recommend using the developer tools on what ever browser you are using and step through the code. It will help you understand what is happening here. As @Arun P Johny said, you need to pass in the button being clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You nee to pass the clicked button reference to the function and then check the id of the button in the `if...else` condition

```
<button id="red" style="background-color:red" type="button" onclick="colorFunction(this)"><font color="white">Red Text</font></button>
<button id="blue" style="background-color:blue" type="button" onclick="colorFunction(this)"><font color="white">Blue Text</font></button>
<button id="blue" style="background-color:black" type="button" onclick="colorFunction(this)"><font color="white">Black Text</font></button>
```

then

```
function colorFunction(button) {
    if (button.id == "red") {
        document.getElementById('test').style.color = "red";
    } else if (button.id == "blue") {
        document.getElementById('test').style.color = "blue";
    } else if (button.id == "blue") {
        document.getElementById('test').style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v1n4xo0t/)

---

If the color and the button id are the same then

```
function colorFunction(button) {
    document.getElementById('test').style.color = button.id;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v1n4xo0t/2/)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if (document.getElementById("red"))
```

returns ANY element which has an id "red" in your page, and will evaluate to true since the element does exist.

What you can do is to make a few changes to your function and function calls and make things a lot simpler:

```
<button id="red" style="background-color:red" type="button" onclick="colorFunction('red')"><font color="white">Red Text</font></button>
<button id="blue" style="background-color:blue" type="button" onclick="colorFunction('blue')"><font color="white">Blue Text</font></button>
<button id="black" style="background-color:black" type="button" onclick="colorFunction('black')"><font color="white">Black Text</font>
```

```
function colorFunction(colorChoice) {
    document.getElementById('test').style.color = colorChoice;
}
```